# Is there a shell one-liner to convert JSON to BSON?

Tags: json

Is there a shell one-liner to convert JSON to BSON?

Something suitable for one-off execution, or a shell script?

`bsondump` from MongoDB goes the inverse way, but I'm clueless as to what I can use to go from JSON to BSON. There's no `bsonundump`, e.g.

Comment: This is definitely not a programming question, I view it as a tools question, but I admit that the distinction is subjective. I am open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Converting JSON to BSON

There's this C implementation that includes a `Makefile` called [`json2bson.c`](https://gist.github.com/algernon/1070514).

#### Converting BSON to JSON

The MongoDB project provides a tool called [`bsondump`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/bsondump/).

> The bsondump converts BSON files into human-readable formats, including JSON. For example, bsondump is useful for reading the output files generated by mongodump.

#### Usage

```
$ bsondump collection.bson > collection.json
```

There's also this Ruby script I found called [`bson2json.rb`](https://gist.github.com/tedsparc/1763326) to convert BSON to JSON as well.

Comment: @nmr - I did find a method using a C app to do JSON to BSON.

Comment: Where does bson.h come from?

Comment: Believe it's part of a mongo library, look at the Makefile.

Comment: Difference between JSON and BSON is that BSON is more rich on data types + is binary. If there are some tools for this, you cannot be 100% sure about the result. Having following json `{ "number": 123 }` You can't be sure whether number 123 is int or long without proper knowledge of schema. MongoDB know what the number is because you specify `NumberLong()` or `NumberInt()` when You're working with the document.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [beesn](https://gitlab.com/monnef/beesn), it converts data both ways. For `JSON -> BSON` use the `-x` switch.

Example:

```
$ beesn -x -i test-data/01.json -o my.bson
```

Disclaimer: I am an author of this tool.

Comment: Is beesn dead or just mature? There has been no activity in the repository for over two years, but there are also no open issues or merge requests, so maybe it is just working, and there is nothing to improve / change?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I think mature. I haven't received any bug reports, tests are passing. The tool itself is very small, just 150 LoC, because it relies heavily on other libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I've made tool for this :) https://mmalcek.github.io/bafi/

The simplest oneline is `./bafi -i inFile.json -f json -t '?{{ toBSON . }}' -o outFile.bson` but there are a lot of other options including stdin/stdout

Answer (score -2):

This shell script converts all the bson files in the dump directory to json files

```
mongodump
for j in ./dump/*
do
 echo Working on directory "$j"
 for i in "$j"/*.bson
 do
  echo Working on file "$i"
  bsondump "$i" >> "$(echo "$i" | sed -e 's/\.bson.*$//')".json
  done
done
```

Comment: This uses ``bsondump`` to convert BSON files to JSON files. The OP knows that this program performs that function, but they want to go the other way; JSON → BSON.

Comment: This does not answer the question.